# I want the sorted list of date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting list of dates and storing it into an array like

```
$arraylist={2022-03-24T12:05:05Z 2022-03-29T12:04:10Z 2022-03-23T12:54:07Z 2022-03-26T13:15:36Z 2022-03-22T10:06:11Z 2022-03-23T09:54:08Z}
```

by using a command `$arrayList +=$listdate`. Now I want the sorted list of date alone like

```
$sortedlist={2022-03-29 2022-03-26 2022-03-24 2022-03-23 2022-03-23 2022-03-22}
```

Not with timing. I am doing these things in PowerShell. The details of date which I am getting is in **string** format not in date-time format. can anyone help me out with this?

I initially split the date with `$arrayList.Split('T')` and stored the date alone in another array. But it is not sorted form. I tried to sort it but I am not getting desired sorted list.

Is there any other way to get desired sorted list of date?

Comment: The thing here is that you only say _"I am getting list of dates and storing it into an array"_, but you don't show how you obtain that list. Also, what you **do** show is not an array. This is simply a case of casting the values in that list of yours to `[datetime]` objects so you can sort anyway you like.

Comment: += kills puppies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your dates in a single string (as per the example of data you have provided) it would be possible to split the string into an array and then convert the array of strings into datetime objects:

```
$DateString = "2022-03-24T12:05:05Z 2022-03-29T12:04:10Z 2022-03-23T12:54:07Z 2022-03-26T13:15:36Z 2022-03-22T10:06:11Z 2022-03-23T09:54:08Z"

$array = $DateString -split " "

$FormattedDates = Foreach ($item in $array){
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($Item, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", $null)
}

$FormattedDates | Sort | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

Comment: You probably want to add a `|ForEach-Object ToString yyyy-MM-dd` at the end of the `Sort` call to produce the output OP desires.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! I missed that :(